# Why is there a data type nagging when using conditional operator in following context?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

```
txtNumOccupations.Text == null ? 0 : int.Parse(txtNumOccupations.Text) 

cmbStatusOccupations.SelectedItem == null ? 0 : cmbStatusOccupations.SelectedItem
```

> Error 1:  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because
>   there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'string'

If the text box is null/empty, the default value should be entered as 0 else take the text box value into int (32).

**Corresponding database field is int. Thus I need to pass the int value of the text box or else pass 0 as default.**

Comment: 0 is not a string you can do "0"

Comment: ...and the result of int.Parse is also not a string

Comment: you must be assigning the whole expression to a string of some sort

Comment: There is a very useful operator for this called null coalesce operator (double question mark `??`).

Comment: Guys, I need to pass the int out of textbox. If it's empty then default to 0. There's no String I need to pass on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant assign int to a string value (`txtNumOccupations.Text`) or mix types in the  conditional operator.

You can do:

```
txtNumOccupations.Text == null ? "0" : txtNumOccupations.Text;
```

Or

```
if(txtNumOccupations.Text == null) txtNumOccupations.Text = "0";
```

Same technique for the 2nd line:

```
if(cmbStatusOccupations.SelectedItem == null) 
   cmbStatusOccupations.SelectedItem = "0";
```

You might also want to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of comparing to `null`

Comment: The first line doesn't throw the error since he's using `int.Parse`.

Comment: ...or even `txtNumOccupations.Text = txtNumOccupations.Text ?? "0"` :-)

Comment: This particular field in DB only takes `int`, so has to be converted accordingly at this point.

Comment: @bonCodigo if `txtNumOccupations.Text` is an int (strange naming) then yes, it would be like in your original question. As for `cmbStatusOccupations.SelectedItem` the error message would suggest that `SelectedItem` is of type string.

Comment: @Magnus both of these controls return 1 or 0 to a bit type field in DB. So As of now it's not an option to enter "0" when the control values are null..